# Removing cycles from an undirected multi graph using Python networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

So I have a undirected multi graph (derived from an ontology), I wish to remove the edges that create cycles (but not all edges, the constituents of the multi graph have to remain connected). Is there a good way of doing this with the networkx package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a unique way to do that for your graph.  But maybe finding a spanning tree will solve your problem?
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree.html

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with

```
def as_spanning_trees(G):
    """
    For a given graph with multiple sub graphs, find the components
    and draw a spanning tree.

    Returns a new Graph with components as spanning trees (i.e. without cycles).

    Parameters
    ---------
    G:        - networkx.Graph
    """

    G2 = nx.Graph()
    # We find the connected constituents of the graph as subgraphs
    graphs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G, copy=False)

    # For each of these graphs we extract the spanning tree, removing the cycles
    for g in graphs:
        T = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(g)
        G2.add_edges_from(T.edges())
        G2.add_nodes_from(T.nodes())

    return G2
```

Comment: `T = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)` will give you the same result  - a minimum spanning forest.